# javascript offsetWidth Undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a plugin for a javascript libary to center elements both vertically and horizontally.

However whenever I try to get the offsetWidth or offsetHeight of an element I get back undefined.

Here's how's I'm getting the offsetWidth:

```
this.offsetWidth;
```

but when i i use:

```
getElementById().offsetWidth;
```

it works fine but i can't use that code i need it to work this way:

```
this.offsetWidth;
```

code:

```
center:function(){
this.css({position: "absolute"});
var screenW = screen.width;
var screenH = screen.height;
var elemW = this.offsetWidth;
alert(elemW);
alert(screenW);
},
```

does this help? this is my objective

```
x$(elem).center();
```

so this would refer to to x$(elem)

Comment: any hints on what this is?  The most common case would be it is the window object.  you would need to make sure your function was called with func.call(getElementById(), [])

Comment: You need to show us the function where you're trying to use `this.offsetWidth`, and how you're calling it. The problem is that `this` is likely referencing `window` when you think it's referencing an HTML element.

Comment: Try `alert(this);` instead of accessing offsetWidth.

Comment: @harry We still don't know what kind of object is `this`. (You can also edit your question if you want to insert multiline code samples).

Comment: @ vbence  what do you mean i'm new to javascript

Comment: @harry We don't know what `elem` is when you call `$(elem).center();` so we still don't know what `this` is in the `center` function.  We need to see where that comes from.